# Trouble converting a char date time to MMDDYY10. using proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to pull in a date time variable that is formatted as a char 55. I would like to be able to do it within my initial pull so I can limit on the date.

Here is the format for field I am pulling in.

```
09/28/2017 00:00:00

TYPE: Char
Len: 55
Format: $55
Informat: $55
```

I have tried so many things to convert it but with no luck. My variable always comes out blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert character datetime to numeric using the input function then use the datepart function to retrieve only the date part and apply proper formatting after.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select datepart(input(date, anydtdtm.)) as date format=MMDDYY10.
from have;
quit;
```

---

```
proc sql; 
connect to hadoop(schema=pharm PROPERTIES='tez.queue.name=user_queue');
create table daily as 
select datepart(input(date, anydtdtm.)) as date format=MMDDYY10.
from connection to hadoop 
(select date from table limit 100)
; 
quit;
```

Comment: Hmmm. I am still getting this error.                                                                                
  ERROR: Prepare error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 
       1:121 cannot recognize input near 'anydtdtm' '.' ')' in select expression

Comment: Are you using an SQL pass-through? Show us the entire code.

Comment: Yes. I am using a pass through to connect to hadoop. I cant really show you my entire code though.

Comment: You are probably using the code inside the pass-through instead of outside.

Comment: proc sql;
connect to hadoop(schema=pharm PROPERTIES='tez.queue.name=user_queue');
create table daily as
select * from connection to hadoop
( SELECT 

  datepart(input(date, anydtdtm.)) as date format=MMDDYY10.


  FROM table limit 100
   
 );
quit;

Comment: Above is the query. I removed a bunch of stuff and changed names.

Comment: This is exactly what I said. Hive will not recognize it. You need to change the `select *` part. See my edited answer